# wcfServiceObject:this cannot convert error

Tags: wcf, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

The line `wcfServiceObject:this` gives an error `cannot convert from ... to ...`.

```
return new[] { new ServiceReplicaListener((context) =>
    new WcfCommunicationListener<IShoppingCartService>(
        wcfServiceObject:this,
        serviceContext:context,
        //
        // The name of the endpoint configured in the ServiceManifest under the Endpoints section
        // that identifies the endpoint that the WCF ServiceHost should listen on.
        //
        endpointResourceName: "WcfServiceEndpoint",

        //
        // Populate the binding information that you want the service to use.
        //
        listenerBinding: WcfUtility.CreateTcpListenerBinding()
    )
)};
```

How do I resolve this problem?

> Code from: https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf/

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I should implement the `interface` for my service. Like the example below for a `ShoppingCartService`:

```
internal sealed class ShoppingCartService : StatefulService, IShoppingCartService
{
    ...
}
```

In this particular case I had to implement the `IShoppingCartService` interface for the `ShoppingCartService`.